# Building PHP dynamic url from modal fields

Tags: php

I've been racking my brains on this one, and think it's beyond me, so I'm looking to you for help.

I have a PHP script that produces a table, where each row has a button.

```
<?php echo ($v['divert_enabled']) ? 'Yes' : 'No' ; ?><br>
    <?php if(!$v['divert_enabled']) : ?>

    <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal<?php echo $v['id']; ?>">Enable</button>

    <!-- Modal For HOSPITAL DIVERT -->
    <div id="myModal<?php echo $v['id']; ?>" class="modal fade" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Apply Hospital Divert</h4>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-body">

      <p>Setting hospital divert for <strong><?php echo $v['name']; ?></strong></p><br>

            <!-- Date time picker -->
            <div id="datetimepicker<?php echo $v['id']; ?>" class="input-append date">
              <input type="text"></input>
              <span class="add-on"><i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i></span>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
              $('#datetimepicker' + <?php echo $v['id']; ?>).datetimepicker({
                format: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm',
                language: 'en-GB',
                pickSeconds: false,
                pick12HourFormat: false
              });
              </script>  

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="sel1">Divert Type:</label>
              <select class="form-control" id="divert_type_<?php echo $v['id']; ?>">
                <option>GP Defelection</option>
                <option>Borderline Deflection</option>
                <option>Full Divert</option>
              </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="sel2">Divert To:</label>
              <select class="form-control" id="divert_to_">
                <option>Somewhere Else</option>
                <option>Even Further</option>
              </select>
          </div>

  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href='?
      action=add_divert&amp;&id=<?php echo $v['id']; ?>&amp;&
      to=LONDON&amp;&
      type=TEST&search=<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['search'])) { echo $_REQUEST['search']; } ?><?php if(isset($_REQUEST['page'])) { echo "&page=".$_REQUEST['page']; } ?><?php if(isset($_REQUEST['sort'])) { echo "&sort=".$_REQUEST['sort']; } ?><?php if(isset($_REQUEST['filter'])) { echo "&filter=".$_REQUEST['filter']; } ?>' class="btn btn-default" role="button">Continue</a>    
  </div>
    </div>

    </div>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

The PHP code will produce a modal box with a unique ID, and unique datetimepicker control.

I need the value of the three fields of the modal to be included in the HREF of the button.

Currently the HREF vars uses ID, TO, and TYPE. ID works fine, but I need to get the values of TO and TYPE (shown as LONDON and TEST) before clicking the button. Obviously these values aren't available on page load, as they are filled in when the modal is shown.

**UPDATED: This is what I ended up using - thanks for the help **

```
        <script>
        $(document).on('click','#WarningModal<?php echo $v['id']; ?> .modal-footer a', function(e)
            {
                e.preventDefault();

                //current timestamp for timing when divert applied.
                var currentdate = new Date(); 
                var datetime = currentdate.getFullYear() + "/"
                        + (currentdate.getMonth()+1)  + "/" 
                        + currentdate.getDate() + " @ "  
                        + currentdate.getHours() + ":"  
                        + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":"
                        + currentdate.getSeconds();
                var uri_date = encodeURI(datetime);

                window.location.href= $(this).attr('href') + '&warn_text=' + $('#warning_<?php echo $v['id']; ?>').val() + '&stamp=' + uri_date + '&target=<?php echo $v['name']; ?>';

            });

      </script>
```

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: what values do you want for TO and TYPE, as you have taken `id=<?php echo $v['id']` then what TO and TYPE will be?

Comment: Where is your jquery Code to fill the values? is `$("body #divert_type_<?php echo $v['id']; ?>").val()` helping?

Comment: @Suyog - I would like TO and TYPE to become the values of the text boxes on the pop up modal form, populated by user.

Comment: @Ashish, the fields on the modal should be populated by user, then reflected in the HREF string before the user hits the submit button. 'LONDON' and 'TEST' are entered for example only and should be replaced by the value of the text boxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do have a solution here below. It's maybe not the most beautifull or elegant way, but I think it will fit your needs.

Add also an ID to `divert_to_` so you will get:

```
<select class="form-control" id="divert_to_<?php echo $v['id']; ?>">
```

Modify the link by remove the `to=` and `type=` part:

```
<a href='?
  action=add_divert&amp;&id=<?php echo $v['id']; ?>&search=<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['search'])) { echo $_REQUEST['search']; } ?><?php if(isset($_REQUEST['page'])) { echo "&page=".$_REQUEST['page']; } ?><?php if(isset($_REQUEST['sort'])) { echo "&sort=".$_REQUEST['sort']; } ?><?php if(isset($_REQUEST['filter'])) { echo "&filter=".$_REQUEST['filter']; } ?>' class="btn btn-default" role="button">Continue</a>
```

Then create an jQuery listener which listens to the link click in the modal:

```
$(document).on('click','#myModal<?php echo $v['id']; ?> .modal-footer a', function(e)
```

Here you can prevent the default action by `e.preventDefault()` and do whatever you want. Here it is possible to get the current link and add the two values. I made a assumption the values are set now, but it's way better if you add an extra check so the values won't be empty. When you added the values to the existing link you can redirect to it through javascript. The full code then can be something like this:

```
<?php echo ($v['divert_enabled']) ? 'Yes' : 'No' ; ?><br>
    <?php if(!$v['divert_enabled']) : ?>

    <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal<?php echo $v['id']; ?>">Enable</button>

    <!-- Modal For HOSPITAL DIVERT -->
    <div id="myModal<?php echo $v['id']; ?>" class="modal fade" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Apply Hospital Divert</h4>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-body">

      <p>Setting hospital divert for <strong><?php echo $v['name']; ?></strong></p><br>

            <!-- Date time picker -->
            <div id="datetimepicker<?php echo $v['id']; ?>" class="input-append date">
              <input type="text"></input>
              <span class="add-on"><i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i></span>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
              $('#datetimepicker' + <?php echo $v['id']; ?>).datetimepicker({
                format: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm',
                language: 'en-GB',
                pickSeconds: false,
                pick12HourFormat: false
              });
              </script>  

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="sel1">Divert Type:</label>
              <select class="form-control" id="divert_type_<?php echo $v['id']; ?>">
                <option>GP Defelection</option>
                <option>Borderline Deflection</option>
                <option>Full Divert</option>
              </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="sel2">Divert To:</label>
              <select class="form-control" id="divert_to_<?php echo $v['id']; ?>">
                <option>Somewhere Else</option>
                <option>Even Further</option>
              </select>
          </div>

  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href='?
      action=add_divert&amp;&id=<?php echo $v['id']; ?>&search=<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['search'])) { echo $_REQUEST['search']; } ?><?php if(isset($_REQUEST['page'])) { echo "&page=".$_REQUEST['page']; } ?><?php if(isset($_REQUEST['sort'])) { echo "&sort=".$_REQUEST['sort']; } ?><?php if(isset($_REQUEST['filter'])) { echo "&filter=".$_REQUEST['filter']; } ?>' class="btn btn-default" role="button">Continue</a>    
  </div>
    </div>

    </div>

    <script>

        $(document).on('click','#myModal<?php echo $v['id']; ?> .modal-footer a', function(e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();

            window.location.href=   $(this).attr('href') + 
                                    '&to='      + $('#divert_to_<?php echo $v['id']; ?> option:selected').text() +
                                    '&type= '   + $('#divert_type_<?php echo $v['id']; ?> option:selected').text();

        });


    </script>

    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Will give that a whirl... stand by!

Comment: Fab, seems to be working well! Thanks very much, I just need to get a date_time string from the other textbox, into the URL, and saved in the DB now!!

Comment: To finish this, I now have: `window.location.href= $(this).attr('href') + '&to=' + $('#divert_to_<?php echo $v['id']; ?> option:selected').text() + '&type= ' + $('#divert_type_<?php echo $v['id']; ?> option:selected').text() + '&until= ' + $('#divert_until_<?php echo $v['id']; ?>').text();` Divert_until is a date time value in a text box, how to encode this with JQuery?

Comment: What is the date time value? Does it displays a date or a number (timestamp). I don't know which value you have or want to have, but maybe you need to change `text()` to `val()` for only the `divert_until` `textbox`

Comment: It displays in format of; 01/01/2015 21:00 and so will fail if passed into URL unformatted, but I'm not sure how to format it so URL and database will accept it! thanks for your help

Comment: Put `encodeURIComponent` around it to encode the date. Normally PHP will automaticly decode the value. Can you try that and give your feedback?

Comment: Thanks, you mean around the JQuery line to give `'&until= ' + $encodeURIComponent(('#divert_until_<?php echo $v['id']; ?>').val());`

Comment: Thanks for your help - I went with this and the script is executing, but the date is not storing in the DB data: `function(e)
           {
              e.preventDefault();
     //function to update HREf attribute with values from modal screen
     var uri = encodeURIComponent($('#divert_until_<?php echo $v['id']; ?>').text());
     
     window.location.href=window.location.href= $(this).attr('href') + '&to=' + $('#divert_to_<?php echo $v['id']; ?> option:selected').text() + '&type= ' + $('#divert_type_<?php echo $v['id']; ?> option:selected').text() + '&until= ' + uri;
         
      });`

Comment: Do you use `$_GET['until']` to receive the value?

Comment: Yes, i've tried with and with a `url decode` preceding it - I'll write a new question.. Thanks for your help so far

Comment: url decoding isn't neseccary anymore in PHP. If you you just use `$_GET['until']` PHP will auto-decode it.

Comment: Still nothing then, even with a fixed string!... Format matches that of the field in MySQL table, so not sure on this one

Comment: Can you update your question with the database insert part? Then I can take a look at it!

Comment: Got it sorted, needed EncodeURI  and changing .text to .val that got it going. thanks!